# Query where clause over array elements inside jsonb PSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, jsonb

I have a JSON node on which I have to write PSQL query,
My table schema name(String),tagValues(jsonb). Example tagValue data is given below

Name_TagsTable

```
 uid |       name(String)|          tagValues(jsonb)
-----+-------------------+-----------------------------
   1 |     myName        |    { "tags": [{"key":"key1","value" : "value1"}, {"key":"key1","value" : "value2"}, {"key":"key3","value" : "value3"}, {"key":"key4","value" : "value4"}] }
```

I need a query that gives me names for which
at least one of the tag in the tags list satisfy the condition
key = 'X' and value = 'Y'

Help me with the query. I am using PSQL 10.0

Comment: You tagged this with jOOQ. Not sure if relevant to your question, but if it is, jOOQ doesn't support the relevant PG operator yet. Use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) instead...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the contains operator `@>` which also works with arrays

```
select *
from name_tagstable
where tagvalues -> 'tags' @> '[{"key": "x", "value": "y"}]';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is working.